# What happens to dynamically allocate objects inside of an object that is deleted?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, destructor

When I use the `delete` keyword on an object is that objects destructor executed?  What if the objected I deleted contains other pointers and I don't delete them, is that a memory leak?

I get a confused a bit sometimes over when to use `delete`.  The problem is worst for me when I pass things around.  I don't know when it's safe to use `delete` for fear of eliminating an object that is being pointed to from somewhere else.

Comment: That is not a issue of `delete` keyword, but of every object destruction. If you leave the scope your object was allocated on heap, the destructor will be called and you reference to the pointer will be lost, the same way if you have created it with `new` and destroyed with `delete`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I use the delete keyword on an object is that objects destructor executed?

**Yes.** That's what the destructor is for.

> What if the objected I deleted contains other pointers and I don't delete them, is that a memory leak?

**Yes.** This is one of the most common sources of memory leaks.

> I don't know when it's safe to use delete for fear of eliminating an object that is being pointed to from somewhere else.

**This is a hard problem.** There is no system that solves it perfectly, but you can get pretty far by using reference-counted smart pointers, and by reducing the number of objects that are shared.

Answer (score 1):

> When I use the delete keyword on an
>   object is that objects destructor
>   executed?

Yes

> What if the objected I deleted
>   contains other pointers and I don't
>   delete them, is that a memory leak?

Yes, unless someone else also has a pointer and that someone else is in charge of deleting them. You can also have problems due to **double deletion**. If you delete a pointer given to you, but someone else has a pointer to that memory, then his pointer now points at nothing. When he goes to use that pointer, his program could crash.

> I don't know when it's safe to use
>   delete for fear of eliminating an
>   object that is being pointed to from
>   somewhere else.

You're not the only one. Its important to establish protocols and conventions between parts of your code about who owns what. What is "producing" objects. What is "consuming" them. You may also wish to use tools such as boost::shared_ptr and boost::weak_ptr to allow for reference counting.

Answer (score 0):

That is a memory leak. That's a very common problem. When you delete an object that you used new to allocate memory for, it will call that objects destructor. The destructor is where you are supposed to provide the implementation to clean up (delete) all of the memory you may have allocated during the lifetime of that object.

Answer (score 0):

If you use new, you must use delete. That will trigger the instance's destructor to be called. If that instance new'd any objects in its constructor (or later) it should delete them in its destructor.

Also, if you new up arrays (new char[20] etc) you must use 'delete []' when deleting, else the behaviour is undefined.

You can avoid a lot of the pain by using std::tr1::shared_ptr, or boost::shared_ptr, which will do reference counting and do the deletes for you, that is instead of:

```
Foo *pFoo = new Foo;
```

do

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<Foo> pFoo(new Foo);
```

then you don't need to do a delete: when the shared_ptr's communal reference count goes to zero it will do the delete for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a leak. See if the [Freestore management](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html) FAQ can add some insight to you understanding.

Answer (score 0):

When you call *delete someObect;* happens something like this:

```
if(someObect != NULL)
{
someObect->~ClassName();// you did ClassName someObect = new ClassName(); 
operator delete(someObect);
}
```

And *operator delete* do as I understand the same thing that *free* do - just frees(deallocates) the memory. But remember, that if you used *new* you cannot use *free*, you must use *delete* and only it.